# Matlab - how do I plot the limit when x reaches 0 in the function (x - sqrt(x)) / sqrt(sin(x))?

Tags: matlab, function, plot, limit

In Matlab - how do I plot the limit when x reaches 0 in the function (x - sqrt(x)) / sqrt(sin(x)) ?

I've just started programming, so I'm very new to this.

I've been trying to plot the function in various ways, one of which is:

```
y = @(x) (x - sqrt.(x))./ (sqrt.(sin.*x));

fplot(y,[0.1 0.9], 200)
```

Which gives the following error code: Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.

I've also tried without the function handle, like this:

```
x = linspace(0.1, pi/2, 200);
y = (x - sqrt.(x))./ (sqrt.(sin.*x));
plot(x, y)
```

Which gives the same error code as the previous one.
I've tried without the dots, tried with different intervals and I don't understand the error code.

Comment: `sqrt.(x)` is illegal syntax in MATLAB. Just write `sqrt(x)`. The square root function is always element-wise. (Well, actually, it is legal syntax if `sqrt` is a struct and `x` evaluates to the name of a field in that struct, which explains the error message you got.)

Comment: @CrisLuengo: "The square root function is always element-wise" is not correct.  `sqrt` is the element-wise one, and `sqrtm` is the matrix square root.

Comment: @Ben: True. with "the square root function" I meant `sqrt`. I had already typed that function name often enough for one comment... :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounds/range of the plot can be changed by adjusting `X_Min, X_Max, Y_Min and Y_Max` as you'd like.

[image: Plotting Functions With Limits]

### Method 1: Using Anonymous Functions

```
y = @(x) (x - sqrt(x))./(sqrt(sin(x)));

X_Min = -5;
X_Max = 20;
Y_Min = -100;
Y_Max = 100;

fplot(y,[X_Min X_Max]);
axis([X_Min X_Max Y_Min Y_Max]);
```

### Method 2: Using Array Inputs/Vectors

This method depends highly on the plotting interval/density. Unfortunately, this method does not show dotted lines on the limits unlike method 1.

```
X_Min = -5;
X_Max = 20;
Y_Min = 0;
Y_Max = 100;

Plotting_Density = 1000;
x = linspace(X_Min, X_Max, Plotting_Density);
y = (x - sqrt(x))./(sqrt(sin(x)));

plot(x, y);
axis([X_Min X_Max Y_Min Y_Max]);
```

### Extension:

The use of the `.` implies elemental operations. Using . will apply the function to all the elements of an array. In this case, it is not necessary to use the `.` operation since the term x is used in an anonymous function.

• "./" -> Division over all elements in array

• ".*" -> Multiplication over all elements in array

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**